# Why can't my custom Lexical React plugin use the LexicalComposerContext?

Tags: javascript, react-context, lexicaljs

```js
function UpdateStatePlugin(props) {
  ...
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  ...
}

function Notes() {
  ...

  const initialConfig = {
    ...
  };

  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      ...
      <UpdateStatePlugin />
    </LexicalComposer>
  )
}
```

This fails with `'useLexicalComposerContext' is not defined`

I followed [this guide](https://lexical.dev/docs/react/create_plugin) and found 1 mention of someone running into a similar problem [here](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/issues/1892). In both cases the structure seems to resemble what I have written. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to define `UpdateStatePlugin` in the same file. The important part is that `UpdateStatePlugin` needs to be a child of `LexicalComposer`.

Your error, `'useLexicalComposerContext' is not defined`, looks like one you'd see if you were missing an import. Try adding this to the top of your file:

```
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext';
```

Comment: Thanks Monty! That's what I ended up doing, though it's not mentioned anywhere in the Lexical docs.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be *defining* `UpdateStatePlugin` within the render body of `Notes`, you should define it outside as its own component.

```js
function UpdateStatePlugin(props) {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    // ...
}

function Notes() {
    // return (...)
}
```

If you are doing this because you are creating `UpdateStatePlugin` to use some outside variable, then you instead should be passing that in as a prop.

```js
function Notes() {
    const [someState] = useState();
    
    function UpdateStatePlugin() {
        useLexicalComposerContext();

        // Let's say you are using `someState` here, this isn't "thinking in React"
        doStuff(someState);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Instead you make the component accept `someState` as a prop, and then pass it in during render

```js
function UpdateStatePlugin(props) {
    useLexicalComposerContext();

    // Takes in `{ someState }` as a prop!
    doStuff(props.someState);
}

function Notes() {
    const [someState] = useState();

    // ...

    return <UpdateStatePlugin someState={someState} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks romellem! I've moved the UpdateStatePlugin definition outside of Notes, but it still produces the same error.